# Can't get jquery variables in php via POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery in another processing.js file and is included in the html file having the form

```
$("#1st_submit").on("click", function(event) {
    var ServiceType =  $("#ServiceType").val();
    var locality = $("#locality").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/revamp/booking.php',
        data: {
            ServiceType: ServiceType,
            locality: locality
        },
        error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message ' + err); },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#1st_booking_form").hide();
            $("#2nd_booking_form").show();
            console.log(data);
            alert("success");   
        }
    });//ajax
})
```

In the PHP code, I am accessing the POST variables as

```
$ServiceType = $_POST['ServiceType'];
$locality = $_POST['locality'];
```

But I am not getting the POST values in the PHP, It's null

HTML Code with the form is this way

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="1st_book" action="">            
            <div class="row" id="1st_booking_form">

               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                      <input class="inputMaterial" id="ServiceType" type="text" value="<?php echo $service_name_s; ?>" name="ServiceType" required>
                       </div>
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">    
                      <input class="inputMaterial" id="locality" type="text" value="<?php echo $locality_s; ?>" name="locality" required>

                </div>


            <br>
            <center><button type="button" class="btn_full" id="1st_submit"> Book Now </button></center>
            </div>
</form>
```

The whole code is working with `type:"GET"`.

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Please validate the data on the PHP side.

Comment: can you add the html for this? are you checking for PHP errors and looking at your console?

Comment: No errors were shown. I've checked printing the post variables, the value is null and in jquery, the alerts are showing the values

Comment: After this line:
var ServiceType =  $("#ServiceType").val();
put an alert(ServiceType) and check its value

Comment: Check your network tab in the console and look for your booking.php page at the end after you send a request.

Comment: console.log(ServiceType); console.log(locality); before ajax request, `print_r($_POST)` in php file.

Comment: It is a jquery variable name as well as id and name of the input in html @JekinKalariya

Comment: did you check `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: @devpro console.log before and inside ajax are printing the values, print_r($_post['ServiceType']); is not printing anything... NULL again

Comment: did you checked browser console? check post values in console

Comment: [*asked 11 mins. ago, prior to "this" comment...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017506/cant-get-jquery-variables-in-php-via-post#comment65385274_39017506) and the guesswork hasn't stopped since.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes you are right king

Comment: It is text/html by default @devpro

Comment: did you check @Fred-ii- last comment?

Comment: I've stayed here long enough and asking for the HTML for this seems to be irrelevant to the OP. Sorry, but I for one will have to pass on this one. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii-.. I'm sorry, I was stuck adding HTML. It says too much of code, So, I had to delete some unnecessary code and add some text to my question... Nothing personal!

Comment: @Saurabh... It is printing `Array
(
)` I've checked it in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mentione #1st_submit is link or simple button?, you have not prevented further event action after this event thats why may be create issue.

```
$(document).on("click","#1st_submit", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/revamp/booking.php', // try url with relative path
        data: {
            ServiceType: $("#ServiceType").val(),
            locality: $("#locality").val()
        },
        error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message ' + err); },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#1st_booking_form").hide();
            $("#2nd_booking_form").show();
            console.log(data);
            alert("success");   
        }
    });//ajax
    return false;
});
```

If Still not working then

Check if you have added any **redirection rules in .htaccess file** , or using header('location: .....') it may be cause same issue....

Comment: also on server side print_r($_POST); die();  and check in console what is returning from server.

Comment: above code is working fine with testing input, so something wrong with input fields.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`
I've added this too as it is a normal button with type="button"...

Comment: still try with this code and try with relative url path instead of full url.

Comment: It is executing that php file, i can get other results from php file through echo, but not post variables @HareshVidja

Comment: what is output of that you getting $_POST or not?

Comment: I guess the post method itself is not posting the values, Everything else is working @HareshVidja

Comment: @devpro.. Nothing is wrong with the input fields, I am getting the values in jquery in alerts, I can see that. Something wrong with POST method

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala turn on error reporting in php and check if there are any error or not.

Comment: My doubt was quite perfect... With `GET`, I am getting the values. But not with POST!

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala: also chk with `method: "POST",`

Comment: @devpro `method:"POST"` is not working ... `method: "GET"` is working instead

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala, have you added any redirection rules in .htaccess file , or using header('location: .....') in php code?.. it may be cause same issue....

Comment: @HareshVidja Oh yes! I did!!! But how can it affect post method and not get method

Comment: @HareshVidja U r absolutely right, I've added an exception in my `.htaccess` file. Even the POST is working now! Thank you!!!

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala, thanks to hear from you, dont forget to up vote my answer and mark as right

Answer (score 0):

That was a problem with redirections in my `.htaccess` file... an exception rule has been added and it is working properly now!